# Is it possible to use a userform property to remove a item in a dictionnary?

Tags: vba, dictionary

So I am trying to remove an item in a dictionary with a dictionary key via a property in a userform. So far, I have succeed to add a new item in dictionary, count item in the dictionary and get an item with userform property. So all of this is functional but I can't get the remove (key) functional.

Here is the property in my userform. (maybe I should use a get property?):

```
Public Property Let Materialremove(ByVal PartNumber As String)
    DicMaterial.Remove (PartNumber)
End Property
```

Here is how I call for my property:

```
If UBidStatus.Materialexists(PartNumber) Then
    UBidStatus.Materialremove (PartNumber)
End If
```

I get a Compile error:

> `Invalid use of property in VBA`

Comment: Shouldn't that be `...(ByVal PartNumber As VARIANT)` ?

Comment: `If DicMaterial.Exists(PartNumber) Then DicMaterial.Remove PartNumber`

Comment: I don't know if this it's the issue, but I would make it be a function.

Comment: @Jeeped, no I used string for other property and putting () doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Doug Glancy, I thought of that but I want to use the properties to protect access to dictionnary.

Comment: Properties are not intended to *take action* - they should be used for setting or retrieving a single value (though that may have secondary side-effects).  You can still encapsulate/protect using a Sub

Comment: Tim is off course right. I meant SUB, not Function.

Comment: @DougGlancy - function is also fine if you (e.g.) return True/False according to whether or not the entry was found/removed.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Doug Glancy, I think you should turn it into a function. I don't think your approach is a good one.  The reason you are having problems is because you are trying to treat a property like a function.  You can make the code work this way:  `UBidStatus.Materialremove = PartNumber` but I strongly advise against that for the sake of the next developer who has to look at the code after you and figure out what it's saying because what you are trying to do makes no logical sense.  **You should turn the property into a function.** You need the assignment operator to make the line work because that is the purpose of a Let property statement: to assign a value to a property.  But since you are trying to force a property to act like a function, it doesn't make any sense when someone tries to read the code.